# Updated to Ubuntu 20.04 - Dock Wont Customize

Tags: gnome, updates, 20.04, settings, dock

I recently updated to 20.04 and I cannot change my dock settings anymore. Tried settings<appearance and its like the toggles just don't do anything. Tried right-clicking free space on the dock, nothing. I'm confused, I installed dconf editor and org<gnome<shell<extensions<dash-to-dock and that doesn't seem to help either. Does this have something to do with the update? I'm sick of small icons on the left, I want big ones on the bottom. Any help apperciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Settings/Appearance (from the dropdown at the top right of 20.04 desktop).

Under the Dock section there are 4 configurations.

Auto-hide the Ddock

Icon size

Show on (when multiple monitors)

Position on screen

Comment: Thanks, turns out for some reason I have two settings menu's... one that works and one that doesn't. I appreciate the help.

Comment: No worries. Please accept the answer (grey icons on the LHS) and even add more information from your solution if you think it will help other users that search for help on "Dock" problems.